# Google Drive Upload Race Condition

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I'm trying to synchronise my application with Google Drive. Right now when we upload a file to Drive we save the file id and metadata locally (to Redis). Then next time we get a push notification from Drive, we compare to see if the file is different to the version we have locally, or if we need to update, delete or create a file.

I'm loading a file like this

```
media_body = MediaFileUpload(local_path,
                             mimetype='binary/octet-stream',
                             chunksize=50000000,
                             resumable=True)
body = {'title': file_name, 'parents': [{'id': parent_id}]}
request = client.files().insert(
    body=body,
    media_body=media_body)
response = None
while response is None:
    status, response = request.next_chunk()
    if status:
         print "Uploaded %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100)
results.append(response)
```

and the `results` are then immediately saved to Redis (file id, metadata...).

The problem is that occasionally we get a push notification, detect that a file has been added to Drive, but we haven't saved that ID to Redis yet. So it registers as a new file meaning we now download it and have two versions of that file.

I think it must be happening by Google Drive sending a push notification for the change before the upload API call returns. I can't add the ID to the Redis before uploading, because we don't know it until the upload function returns... Can anyone suggest a possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused (or at least made worse) by the fact you are creating the file and uploading the media contents in a single command. If you decouple the file from the media (ie. insert the file with no contents, and then update it with the contents), you should be OK. Remember that if you do this, you will receive 2 notifications, one for the insert and one for the updated content.

Alternatively, have logic like this ...

```
havePendingInsert = true
request = client.files().insert(...  // your line 6
havePendingInsert = false
processAnyCachedPushNotifications()

and in your module which deals with push notifications...
if (havePendingInsert) {
    storeNotificationInCache()
} else {
    processNotificationNow()
}
```